# Youtube iframe API - Android fullscreen

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the YouTube iframe api to embed a video.
When playing the video on an iPhone, the video automatically switches to full screen mode. I was wondering if it's possible to force the same behavior on an Android? (currently the video is played inline, which doesn't look so good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to automatically play the video fullscreen. The closest you could get is to put the player in a fullscreen div and autoplay it using the url params:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fSy6uh-GjCc?controls=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the `fullscreen div`? in your example the `allowfullscreen` is bound to iframe, not to a div (as I understand, a parent div). Please provide the full sample if possible

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh you would use css to fill the browser with the iframe e.g.
iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index:2; }